# <Class X> does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter - how to rewrite this method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have been given this code:

```
    public async Task myServerResponse()
    {
        Task.Run(new Func<Task>(..));
        await this.ConnectSomewhere(...); 
        ...
        // this method does not have any return
    }


    private async Task Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            bool myFlag = true;
            var taskAwaiter = this.myServerResponse().GetAwaiter();
            if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
            {
                await taskAwaiter;
                taskAwaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
                myFlag = false;
            }
            if (myFlag)
                taskAwaiter.GetResult();
            
            ...
```

However, on line where it says `await taskAwaiter;` it shows

> Error CS1061 : 'TaskAwaiter' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'TaskAwaiter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can be this method be rewritten correctly? I think something is overcomplicated approach there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems that you could just use `async await` and remove the rest of the stuff:

```
 private async Task Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            await this.myServerResponse();
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you, worked. Last question - I've updated question with real-use of some strange flag. Could you include that case too in your answer?

Comment: Well the updated code doesn't make much sense. An attempt is made to mimic the async await behavior, and a bad one I must say. We try to get the result only if it is 'ready' but `await this.myServerResponse();` already covers that bit. Another matter is what to do with the result, you might want to save it to a variable and use later but this depends on task at hand